# Can't access site on EC2 linux instance via public ip

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I've been experimenting with EC2 Linux for a couple days. And i've installed chef-server 12.8.0 and chef-manage that used nginx server to host chef-manage web ui.

when i'm trying to browse:

**Localhost :** https://127.0.0.1 - inside server it's working

**Public DNS :** https://ec2-54-211-175-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com - inside server working but not outside

**Public IP :** https://54.211.175.150 - not working on both side.

and have been banging my head against simply even being able to access the sample hosted site.

I don't much experience with the ec2 server. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are aware of [security zones](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html) and that you have to allow incoming traffic explicitly in AWS?

Answer (score 1):

I bet you need to work your [security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#vpc-security-groups)

Open the EC2 console and check the security group rules for your ec2 instance, make sure you allow HTTPS (port 443) inbound connection on your instance and it will be available for you

Comment: Maybe port 443 instead?

Comment: arg my bad ... miss that its mentioned https so indeed 443

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned a Chef Server if you want the Web UI to work with the EC2 Public DNS this are the setting you need to make to the `/etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb` file. If you don't make the below changes then you will be able to access the UI only on the localhost like in your case.

```
lb[:enable] = "false"
lb[:web_ui_fqdn] = "ec2-54-211-175-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com"

nginx[:server_name] = "ec2-54-211-175-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
nginx[:url] = "https://ec2-54-211-175-150.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
nginx[:enable_non_ssl] = "true"
```

After you make above changes and still you are not able to access the Web UI for Chef then check your Security group for your EC2 instance and see if you have port 80 and port 443 open in that security group.